# How to convert a nested flatten into Standard SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Currently using BigQuery From google. My legacy query looks like:

```
Select * FROM FLATTEN(FLATTEN([DB.table1], record.atr), record.atr.value) 
WHERE record.atr.value IN "1"
```

I understand [BigQuery now automatically flattens](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-flatten-data-using-google-bigquerys-legacy-vs-standard-sql/) tables so i thought this would do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM `DB.table1`
WHERE record.atr.value IN "1"
```

However i get an error **Error: Cannot access field value on a value with type ARRAY, sv ARRAY, ...>> at [2:17]**

How can i convert this to Standard SQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigQuery does not automatically flatten arrays when using standard SQL; the link that you provided indicates the opposite. In your case, the query would be something like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(value), value
FROM `Db.table1`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(record.atr) AS atr
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(atr.value) AS value;
```

If you want to get a row  even for empty arrays, you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(value), value
FROM `Db.table1`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(record.atr) AS atr
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(atr.value) AS value;
```

Here is a sample query that you can try running:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<x STRING, value ARRAY<INT64>>>[('foo', [1, 2]), ('bar', [3, 4, 5])] AS atr) AS record UNION ALL
  SELECT STRUCT(ARRAY<STRUCT<x STRING, value ARRAY<INT64>>>[('baz', [6, 7])])
)
SELECT * EXCEPT (value)
FROM Input
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(record.atr) AS atr
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(atr.value) AS value;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Now i understand, it will flatten tables, but not arrays automatically. I'll try it out.

Comment: Okay, new error: "Column atr in SELECT * EXCEPT list does not exist at [1:18]"

Comment: Try just using `SELECT *` without `EXCEPT (atr)`.

Comment: Query was syntatically correct but failed: **Error: Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): value**

Comment: It was `value` that I needed to put in the `EXCEPT` list...I updated the answer.

Comment: Yup! That did it, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

> How can i convert this to Standard SQL query?
>   SELECT * FROM `DB.table1`
>   WHERE record.atr.value IN "1"

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `DB.table1`
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM UNNEST(record.atr) AS atr, 
              UNNEST(atr.value) AS val 
        WHERE val IN ('1')) > 0
```

You can test it with dummy data (partially borrowed from Elliott's example)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `DB.table1` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, STRUCT([STRUCT<x STRING, value ARRAY<STRING>>('foo', ['1', '2']), ('bar', ['3', '4', '5'])] AS atr) AS record UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, STRUCT([STRUCT<x STRING, value ARRAY<STRING>>('baz', ['6', '7'])])
)
SELECT *
FROM `DB.table1`
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) 
        FROM UNNEST(record.atr) AS atr, 
              UNNEST(atr.value) AS val 
        WHERE val IN ('1')) > 0
```