# How to flatten a struct in bigquery standard sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

With the below standard sql query, I can return a table of structs in BigQuery that contains all fields from both a and b.

```
SELECT a, b
FROM first_table a
JOIN second_table b
ON a.key = b.key;
```

The resulting table schema will have `a` as RECORD, and `b` as RECORD, with a.field1, a.field2, b.field1, b.field2, etc. all having their original types.

If I save this table as a_join_b and then query it in legacy_sql:

```
SELECT *
FROM a_join_b
;
```

it will flatten the structs and provide a table with fields named a_field1, a_field2, ..., b_field1, b_field2.  Note the underscores between the table names and the field names, and that a and b can have similar field names.

Is there a way in BigQuery Standard SQL to flatten a table without referring to individual record names?  I've looked at UNNEST in [How to convert a nested flatten into Standard SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041316/how-to-convert-a-nested-flatten-into-standard-sql) but the solution seems to require joining unnested fields that must be named.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` and `b` don't have arrays, it's very simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM first_table a
JOIN second_table b
USING (key)
```

or

```
SELECT a.*, b.* EXCEPT (key)
FROM first_table a
JOIN second_table b
ON a.key = b.key
```

If they do contain arrays, then it's dependent on the layout of those (`UNNEST` refers to arrays only, so I suspect they may). Can you clarify the layout of the tables if so?

Comment: Thanks, but these queries don't prepend the table names a and b.  Also, they don't work if a and b have fields with the same names. Error: Duplicate column names in the result are not supported.  The tables don't contain arrays.  Consider the query:  ```#standardSQL
WITH first_table AS (
  SELECT 777 AS key, 1 AS x, 2 AS y, 3 AS z
),
second_table  AS (
  SELECT 777 AS key, 4 AS x, 5 AS y, 6 AS z
)
SELECT *
FROM first_table AS a
JOIN second_table AS b 
USING (key)```

Comment: What would be the result you'd want from this example?

Comment: The acknowledged solution has been provided by Mikhail Berlyant in his reply to the "Is there a way to prepend joined tablename in BigQuery Standard SQL?" question in stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45692560/is-there-a-way-to-prepend-joined-tablename-in-bigquery-standard-sql .